# Can you create a language specific extension command?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When developing VSCode extensions, is it possible to create an extension command that is only available for certain languages?

In your `package.json` manifest, you can activate your extension per language:

```json
"activationEvents": [
    "onLanguage:html"
]
```

However, a command is still there in the command palette for all extensions. It just won't work until the extension has been activated.

I can't figure out how to make a command, only appear for specific languages... You can define a command like this:

```json
"contributes": {
    "commands": [{
        "command": "extension.sayHello",
        "title": "Hello World"
    }]
}
```

But this command is available for all languages in the command palette. The specific command I want to create really only makes sense, in my example, for the HTML language. The command specifically queries an API somewhere and then inserts some HTML into the current file. So obviously it wouldn't make sense to use this command for other languages like `python` or `ruby` etc.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for this was added in VSCode 1.10: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_context-specific-visibility-of-command-palette-menu-items

In your `package.json`:

```json
"commands": [{
    "command": "extension.sayHello",
    "title": "Hello World"
}],
"menus": {
    "commandPalette": [{
        "command": "extension.sayHello",
        "when": "editorLangId == html"
    }]
}
```